# Is it possible to tell ansible not to use ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, ansible

My `~/.ssh/config` file is interfering with ansible, I use a lot of abbreviations in there to make my life easier when logging onto servers.

for example in:

```
Host te*
     HostName %h.example.com
     User test
```

In my ansible hosts file I have:

```
[servers]
te1.exmaple.com
te2.example.com
```

which means when I run ansible, the connection will fail because it will use my ssh config file and try to connect to `te1.example.com.example.com`.

I know I could modify ansible hosts to just be te1 and let ssh config add the rest of the domain, but I know that other members of my team don't have their .ssh/config set up like me so this isn't really an option, and tbh is the easy route which will end up causing problems for others.

Is there a way in ansible to tell it not to use mine or anyone else `.ssh/config` file?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS` [parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args) in `ansible.cfg` for that. The required ssh parameter is `-F configfile` which has the following meaning:

> `-F configfile`
>
> Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a
> configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide
> configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored.  The default
> for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.

So your `ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS` with the defaults in in `ansible.cfg` would then look like this:

```
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -F /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

*ssh -F* allows you to specify "an alternative per-user configuration file".

> -F configfile
>                Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a configuration file is given on the command line, the
>                system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored.  The default for the per-user configuration
>                file is ~/.ssh/config.

In Ansible you  can configure it by [ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args).

For example in [ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) you can set it to any file that fits your needs.

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ...
```

Or, you might want to create a separate user (let's say *ansible-admin*) set her ~/.ssh/config and use it to run ansible.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in the end. I added this to my ansible.cgf file.

`[all:vars] ansible_ssh_common_args = '-F /dev/null'`

Thanks to all who answered :)